# After installing updates and rebooting server SSH keys modified to use hostname instead of IP

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

After a recent update on my Ubuntu 14.04 AWS EC2 server my remote machines could no longer ssh in. 
Checking the syslog on the EC2 I found:

```
Jun 26 02:27:06 ec2: #############################################################
Jun 26 02:27:06 ec2: -----BEGIN SSH HOST KEY FINGERPRINTS-----
Jun 26 02:27:06 ec2: 256 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  user@hostname.com (ECDSA)
Jun 26 02:27:06 ec2: -----END SSH HOST KEY FINGERPRINTS-----
Jun 26 02:27:06 ec2: #############################################################
```

Switching over to my remote machine i did some digging and found this error message:

```
The authenticity of host ‘[hostname]:port ([###.###.###.###]:port)’ can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
```

running ‘ssh-keygen -l -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts’ returns:

```
256 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx |1|aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa=|aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa= (ECDSA)
256 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx |1|bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb=|bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb= (ECDSA)
```

And using ‘ssh-keygen -H -F’
I found out the old key was using [hostname]:443
and the new key is using [ipaddress]:443

I have 3 questions:
1. Why was the authenticity in question if the fingerprint and key matched? I was under the impression the hashes were purely informational.
2. What would cause the key to re-generate with the ip address instead of the hostname?
3. Is there a way to re-generate the keys with the hostname again?

In the short term I will just update the known_hosts file with both keys, I would just like more understanding on why/who this happened and my searching is returning results that are far too low level.